# Can I call clearInterval on the same id twice?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this cumbersome logic :

```
function handle_register_after_pressed(){
    if (typeof handle_register_after_pressed.sid !== "undefined" && ff_handle_register_after_pressed.sid)
    {
        clearInterval(handle_register_after_pressed.sid);
        ff_handle_register_after_pressed.sid = 0;
    }
    handle_register_after_pressed.sid = setInterval(function(){},1000);
}
```

I want to cancel the old `setInterval` and restart it if the function is called again.

Is it possible to use this way:

```
function handle_register_after_pressed(){
     if (typeof handle_register_after_pressed.sid !== "undefined" )
     {
         clearInterval(handle_register_after_pressed.sid);
     }
     handle_register_after_pressed.sid = setInterval(function(){},1000);
 }
```

So I want to ask :

- if the id's returned from `setTimeout`, `clearInterval` are unique and ever increasing?
- calling `setTimeout`, `clearInterval` **again** on same returned id is no problem
- when id is 0 or null or `undefined` then also we can call `setTimeout`, `clearInterval` without it generating exceptions.

Comment: So why not define a variable in the global scope and clear/reset it within the function... maybe have the interval check it's current time too so when it hit's **0** it can reset or clear, depending on your expectations... Also what do you mean by *"on the same id twice"*? You mean call clearinterval on multiple with the same ID or on the same ONE twice?

Comment: `typeof handle_register_after_pressed.sid !== UNDEFINED` does nothing.  An undefined value evaluates as falsey, your `if` statement can only ever evaluate to true when `handle_register_after_pressed.sid` is defined, and since the return value of setInterval is non-zero it should only be true when you have a valid interval

Answer (score 4):

The return value of setInterval is just a unique number you use to pass back to clearInterval. It is not an object with any additional information.

so this code `if (typeof handle_register_after_pressed.sid !== "undefined" )` will not work, since handle_register_after_pressed.sid will not be set to undefined or null after you do clearInterval.

If you wish to know if an interval is cleared, you need to come up with a custom  solution like below,

```
function mySetInterval(fn, interval) {
    var id = setInterval(fn, interval);
    this.cleared = false;
    this.clear = function () {
        this.cleared = true;
        clearInterval(id);
    };
}
```

and then call it like this,

```
var t = new mySetInterval(function () {
    console.log('this is a test');
}, 5000);
console.log(t.cleared); // false
t.clear();
console.log(t.cleared); // true
```

To answer the rest of your question,

1. yes, the id returned from setTimeout and setInterval is unique for the lifetime of the current webpage. Also, the pool of IDs used by setInterval() and setTimeout() is shared, meaning it's an ever-increasing counter.
2. No problem if you call clearInterval on the same id. Once an interval id is generated, it is not returned to the pool of IDs even after clearing that interval (Until the lifetime of the current web page).
3. It won't create an issue if you call clearInterval with invalid parameters, like null or undefined or 0. It does not throw any Exception. you're safe.